# How to compute a thermodynamic derivative (like $-(dE/dV)_T$) from simulation output where there is only kinetic and potential energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, molecular-dynamics

Apologies in advance for what may be a very basic question.  I want to use output from an NPT molecular dynamics simulation to compute data for a wider piece of work.  The person who ran the simulation is no longer around.

I need to compute this (where $T$ is a subscript that means "at constant temperature" and $E$ is internal energy):

$$- \left (\frac {\partial E}{\partial V } \right)_T $$

I have a simulation output file that has these columns:

```
Time, temperature, kinetic energy, potential energy, total energy
```

I think I need to add the kinetic and potential energy columns to get the internal energy.  But how do I compute the partial of $E$ with respect to $V$ at constant $T$?  E.g.,

- what is the reference point for calculating the delta?
- Is it $E$ at one time step minus $E$ at the previous time step?

I have another file that provides the volume at each time step.  It fluctuates because this is an NPT simulation.

Comment: Note that you can use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/743391) for typesetting the equations (as I have did it).:-)

Comment: This sort of question would also fit in on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/#)

Comment: There is also a thermodynamics tag on MMSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compute the derivative of $E$ with respect to $V$, you should first compute $E(V)$. Note that here $E$ and $V$ are **not** the instantaneous values you get from your simulation but their ensemble (or time) averages. This means that a simulation at fixed $N$, $P$ and $T$ yields a single value of $E$ and a single value $V$ (provided you are not simulating a phase-separating system, which is a different beast altogether).

In general the internal energy of a system $E$ is **the average** of its instantaneous potential energy, while $V$ is **the average** of the instantaneous volume. Therefore, if you want to compute $-(\partial E / \partial V)T$ you first run simulations along an isotherm (that is, at fixed $T$) while changing $P$. For each value of $P$ you compute the average volume $V$ and the average potential energy $E$, which will give you the $E(V)$ function, which you can now derive.